# How to generate a report in python containing the difference of last and first row of multiple csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, glob

I have multiple csv files in the below format:

**CSV File 1:**

[image]

**CSV File 2:**

[image]

The report needs to be generated containing the difference of last and first row of each csv file as below:

[image]

The below code calculates the difference between the last and first row. How do we write the results into a separate file in the report format specified above?

```py
def csv_subtract():
    # this is the extension you want to detect
    extension = '.csv'
    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(csv_file_path):
        for f in files_list:
            if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == extension:
                file_name_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                df = pd.read_csv(file_name_path)
                diff_row = (df.iloc[len(df.index) - 1] - df.iloc[0]).to_frame()
```

Comment: Are `f` and `file_name` different objects?

Comment: They are the same I just corrected, it was a typo

Comment: Are you asking how to *accumulate* all the results into a single  container? Or "how do I save a DataFrame as a csv file?". Or "how do I add a column to a DataFrame with the filename?"

Comment: I need to do a combination of all of the above in the below order:

1. Read each csv file

2. Calculate the difference between last & first row, repeat the same for all csv files

3. Accumulate the results for each file into a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using your code

```py
def csv_subtract():
    # this is the extension you want to detect
    extension = '.csv'
    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(csv_file_path):
        df_dict = {}
        for f in files_list:
            if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == extension:
                file_name_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                df = pd.read_csv(file_name_path)
                # simplified indexing
                # diff_row = (df.iloc[len(df.index) - 1] - df.iloc[0]).to_frame()  # old
                diff_row = (df.iloc[-1] - df.iloc[0]).to_frame()  # new
                df_dict[f] = diff_row
    
        out = pd.concat(df_dict, names=["File Name"])
        out.to_csv("path/to/report.csv")
```

## Another Approach

Concatenate all the data upon read, groupby the file names, and calculate the differences within each group.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # some fake data for setup
    np.random.seed(1)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
        columns=list("abcde")
    )
    np.random.seed(2)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
        columns=list("abcde")
    )

    # I concatenate all dfs into one and use `keys` to identify which rows
    # belong to which df
    # in your function you could set keys to the file names
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["df1", "df2"], names=["file_name"])

    # groupby the keys and calculate the difference between 0th and -1st rows
    out = df.groupby("file_name").apply(lambda df: df.iloc[-1] - df.iloc[0])

    print(out)
```

```
                  a         b        c         d         e
file_name                                                 
df1        0.383723  0.247937  0.31331  0.389990  0.729633
df2        0.069251  0.039360 -0.12154 -0.338791 -0.293208
```

Last step is to save this to a .CSV using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
out.to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

## Concatenating Files Via Function

```py
from glob import iglob

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def read_df_rec(path: str, fn_regex: str = ".csv"):
    # generate all *.csv paths in root_dir
    csv_paths = list(iglob(f"*{fn_regex}", root_dir=path, recursive=True))
    # generator that reads all csv files into pd.DataFrames
    df_gen = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_paths)
    # concat the `df_gen` values and name each with it's respective `csv_path`
    df = pd.concat(objs=df_gen,
                   keys=csv_paths,  # assign file names here
                   names=["File Name"])  # name index here
    # group by file name and calculate difference between last and first row
    out = df.groupby("File Name").apply(lambda df: df.iloc[-1].sub(df.iloc[0]))
    return out

# make some fake data and save to current directory
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
    columns=list("abcde")
)

np.random.seed(2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
    columns=list("abcde")
)

df1.to_csv("df1.csv", index=False)
df2.to_csv("df2.csv", index=False)

# read all csv files from current directory (".")
out = read_df_rec(path=".")

print(out)
```

```
                  a         b        c         d         e
File Name                                                 
df1.csv    0.383723  0.247937  0.31331  0.389990  0.729633
df2.csv    0.069251  0.039360 -0.12154 -0.338791 -0.293208
```

## Concatenating Files in Nested Directories using Recursion and Reducing File Names to their Stems

```py
from glob import iglob
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def read_df_rec(path: str, fn_regex: str = ".csv"):
    # recursively generate all *.csv paths starting in root 
    # directory and subdirectories
    csv_paths = list(iglob(f"**/*{fn_regex}", root_dir=path,
                           recursive=True))
    # generator that reads all csv files into pd.DataFrames
    df_gen = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_paths)
    # extract path stems from csv_paths
    file_names = (Path(path).stem for path in csv_paths)
    # concat the `df_gen` values and name each with it's 
    # respective `csv_path`
    df = pd.concat(objs=df_gen,
                   keys=file_names,  # assign file names here
                   names=["File Name"])  # name index here
    # group by file name and calculate difference between 
    # last and first row
    out = df.groupby("File Name").apply(
        lambda df: df.iloc[-1].sub(df.iloc[0])
    )
    return out

# make some fake data and save to different directories
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
    columns=list("abcde")
)

np.random.seed(2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random(size=(5, 5)),
    columns=list("abcde")
)

# different directory per file
df1.to_csv("Untitled Folder/df1.csv", index=False)
df2.to_csv("Untitled Folder 1/df2.csv", index=False)

# read all csv files starting in current directory (".")
out = read_df_rec(path=".")

print(out)
```

```
                  a         b        c         d         e
File Name                                                 
df1        0.383723  0.247937  0.31331  0.389990  0.729633
df2        0.069251  0.039360 -0.12154 -0.338791 -0.293208
```

Comment: Could you please show in the second approach you have suggested how can we concatenate multiple csv into  single data frame when provided the file path

I tried the below code but not able to get the difference using this method:

def read_df_rec(path, fn_regex=r'*.csv'):
    return pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in iglob(
        join(path, '**', fn_regex), recursive=True)), ignore_index=True)

Comment: @user2077648 -- please see updated answer **Concatenating Files Via Function**

Comment: This concatenating approach works only when files are in the same directory as the script, is there a way to run this script for files in any path. 

I tried the below script it works but gives the entire file path in the output, is there a way to print only the file name excluding the path?

Comment: def csv_path_list(file_path: str, extension='.csv'):
    file_path_list = []
    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(file_path):
        for file_name in files_list:
            if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
                file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                print(file_name)
                # This is the full path of the filter file
                print(file_name_path)
                file_path_list.append(file_name_path)
    return file_path_list

Comment: @user2077648 -- please see updated answer **Concatenating Files in Nested Directories using Recursion and Reducing File Names to their Stems**